# document.forms['form_preview'] Undefined Error: Javascript

Tags: javascript, forms

I'm facing problem as of bellow,

```
  <form name="form_preview" id="form_preview" action="xxxx.php" method="POST" target="iframe_p">
 <input type="hidden" name="post_data" id="post_data" value="xxxxxxxx">
 </form>
    <script language="JavaScript">

        document.forms['form_preview'].submit();

    </script>
```

I'm having nested forms and trying to submit an inner form. This condition throws me an error like "document.forms['form_preview'] undefined"

please Help!

Answer (score 0):

`document.forms` is somehow deprecated. Use `document.getElementById('form_preview').submit();` instead. Also make sure the DOM is fully loaded before trying to manipulate its elements ([window.onload](http://javascript.about.com/library/blonload.htm)).

Comment: hi, even document.getElementById('form_preview').submit(); 
did'nt work for me

Comment: also tried window.onload=document.forms['form_preview'].submit();
but no success :(

Comment: try: `window.onload = function() { document.getElementById('form_preview').submit() };`